# Use sass function result in function

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I've got some breakpoints, and a mixin for handling them:

```scss
$breakpoints: (
    'xs': (max-width: 768px),
    'sm': (min-width: 768px),
    'md': (min-width: 992px),
    'lg': (mix-width: 1200px),
) !default;

@mixin screen($breakpoint) {
    @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
        @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint))} {
           @content;
         }
     } @else {
        @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Available breakpoints are: #{map-keys($breakpoints)}.";
    }
}
```

Now what I like is that the pixel values will go through a `em()` function.

That function looks like this:

```scss
@function em($pixels, $context: $font-initial-size) {
   @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
}
```

Now I would like this to look like so:

```scss
$breakpoints: (
    'xs': (max-width: em(768px)),
    'sm': (min-width: em(768px)),
    'md': (min-width: em(992px)),
    'lg': (mix-width: em(1200px)),
) !default;
```

But then the CSS output is this:

```css
@media (min-width: em(768px)) {
```

... and it should be:

```css
@media (min-width: 48em) {
```

So how to return the result of a sass function within a sass function?

I tried adding `#{}` to the $breakpoint... but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is not working because, you need to have your function defined before you use it inside sass file. Move `em` function to the top of the file to fix the issue:

```scss
$font-initial-size: 16px;

@function em($pixels, $context: $font-initial-size) {
  @return #{$pixels / $context}em;
}

$breakpoints: (
    "xs": (max-width: em(768px)),
    "sm": (min-width: em(768px)),
    "md": (min-width: em(992px)),
    "lg": (max-width: em(1200px))
) !default;

@mixin screen($breakpoint) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint))} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else {
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. " + "Available breakpoints are: #{map-keys($breakpoints)}.";
  }
}

 @include screen('sm') {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes! You are right, it was an issue with the order of the functions being loaded. One last question; whould you use EM for these media query values or REM? If I understand correctly EM is based on the base font size. And REM is always 16px. So do I want my layout breakpoints to be variable to the base font size...

Comment: There is no guarantee that rem will have 16px, most browsers do set it to 16 but you can still override it. In general, I do agree using rem is better than using em, but I would say that it depends on your particular use case so test it and if rem works for you , great!